# get separated 0 and 1 from dec2base in MATLAB (i.e. in a vector rather than 1x1 array)

Tags: matlab, binary

I need to have the output of  MATLAB 'dec2base' function such that 0 and 1 (if base=2) are separated.

For example dec2base(11,2) = '1011' which is in char format.

I used str2num(dec2base(11,2)) and the output is in double format in 1x1 matrix as [1011], HOWEVERE, what I desire is to take the output in 1x4 vecto as [1 0 1 1].

Thank you very much in advance for your useful answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have it as 1x4 character array (not 1x1 array). If you want to convert it to 1x4 double array, subtract `'0'` from it i.e.

```
dec2base(11,2)-'0'
```